# Find Parent Element in selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find parent element of an element. I tried using xpath '..', './..', .parent etc. All the solutions I found online give me the parent of some other similar element somehow. Please help.

```
<div ng-repeat="menu in category.refineDynList" ng-if="menu.removableOptions.length || menu.availableOptions.length" class="">
  <a class="left-sidebar__header" href=""><span>Category</span></a>
  <div class="left-sidebar__category-container">
    <!-- ngIf: menu.showMore -->
    <refine-search ng-if="menu.showMore" link="menu.showMore.link" label="menu.showMore.label" class="">
      <div class="left-sidebar__search-container">
        <input type="search" class="left-sidebar__search ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="search.label" ng-click="handleSearchClicks()" placeholder="Show More Refinements..."><!-- ngIf: showRefinements -->
      </div>
    </refine-search>
    <!-- end ngIf: menu.showMore --><!-- ngRepeat: option in menu.removableOptions --><!-- ngRepeat: option in menu.availableOptions -->
  </div>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
 parent_element = header_element.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Which _parent element_ of which _element_?

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to find parent element of "<a class="left-sidebar__header" href=""><span>Category</span></a>"

Comment: The linkText **Category** have an ancestor `<a>` tag. Are you trying to locate that? What is your exact _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?